# Mongo throwing 'topology was destroyed' error after calling Collection.drop with node.js MongoDB Driverr

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Every time when I call the drop collection function with the MongoDB Driver. This error is thrown:

> "MongoError: topology was destroyed".

Here is my code:

```
var dropCollection = function(db){
    let collectionA = db.Collection('CollectionA');
    collectionA.drop(function(err, delOK) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        if (delOK) console.log("Collection deleted");

    });
};
MongoClient.connect(connectionUrl, null, function(err, db){
    let current_db = db.db(dbName);
    dropCollection(current_db);
    db.close();
});
```

I have tried other function like Collection.find. It runs without error. It seems that the error is showing that it lost the connection to the DB.

I am using:
native node driver 2.2.24
MongoDB version 3.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `db.close()` was called **before** the `drop()` command was executed. It is expected, due to the way node's callback mechanism works.

Assuming the collection `CollectionA` exists, moving the `db.close()` into the `drop()` callback should work as expected:

```
var dropCollection = function(db){
    let collectionA = db.collection('CollectionA');
    collectionA.drop(function(err, delOK) {
        if (err) console.log('Error here:' + err);
        if (delOK) console.log("Collection deleted");
        db.close();  // move db.close() here to ensure that
                     // it's called *after* the drop()
    });
};
MongoClient.connect(url, null, function(err, db){
    let current_db = db.db(dbName);
    dropCollection(current_db);
});
```

If you see an error like `ns not found`, then it means that `CollectionA` doesn't exist.